# What is an unnamed lvalue?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, lvalue, value-categories

I have seen in the draft [N4268](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html) a concept called "unnamed lvalue" in the striked-though part below

> [ Note:  <s>Temporaries, unnamed lvalues, and named lvalues with no linkage are</s> A temporary object is not an acceptable template-arguments when the corresponding template-parameter has reference type. [ Example: ... ] ]

I have searched a lot but neither stackoverflow nor google gave me an answer.
I only found this post about value categories

[What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601661/5076707)

But it didn't help.

Comment: [On how to recognize Rvalue or Lvalue reference and if-it-has-a-name rule](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27554296/3953764)

Comment: `*ptr` is an example of an lvalue without a name

Comment: A function call expression, where the said function has return type of lvalue reference, is also an unnamed lvalue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all lvalue expressions have names. In fact, the wording in N4296 gives us some examples:

> For a non-type template-parameter of reference or pointer type, the
>   value of the constant expression shall not refer to (or for a pointer
>   type, shall not be the address of):
>
> - a subobject (1.8),
> - a temporary object (12.2),
> - a string literal (2.14.5),
> - the result of a typeid expression (5.2.8), or
> - a predefined **func** variable (8.4.1).

Furthermore, [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)'s information on value categories goes into detail about lvalues:

> An lvalue is an expression that identifies a non-temporary object or a
>   non-member function.
>
> The following expressions are lvalues:
>
> - The name of a variable or function in scope, regardless of type, such as std::cin or std::endl. Even if the variable's type is rvalue
>     reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue
>     expression.
> - Function call or overloaded operator expression if the function's or overloaded operator's return type is an lvalue reference, such as
>     std::getline(std::cin, str) or std::cout << 1 or str1 = str2 or ++iter
> - Built-in pre-increment and pre-decrement, dereference, assignment and compound assignment, subscript (except on an array xvalue), member
>     access (except for non-static non-reference members of xvalues, member
>     enumerators, and non-static member functions), member access through
>     pointer to data member if the left-hand operand is lvalue, comma
>     operator if the right-hand operand is lvalue, ternary conditional if
>     the second and third operands are lvalues.
> - Cast expression to lvalue reference type.
> - String literal

However, this is all irrelevant as the scope of the change is the proposal [Allow constant evaluation for all non-type template arguments](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4268.html).